# Accessibilityrecord.getBeforeText

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibilityservice

I'm developing an application to get the HTTP referrer. I want to know from which web page the user comes from. I'm trying to use Accessibilityrecord.getBeforeText(). For more clarification, imagine I am on a web page with "URL = kotlinProvider.ir" Then I click on a link and go to another web page with "URL = kotlin.com". Does AccessibilityRecord have any function that gets the previous web page as "kotlinProvider.ir" and it changed to "kotlin.com"? I filtered events by packageName,className, ID, and event types to listen to the search bar changes.
I also used

```
 val previousText = event.beforeText.toString()
```

but it gives information about char sequence changes. I appreciate any help